# Computationally estimate $E[f(\hat \beta_1 X)]$ where $\hat \beta_1$ is the estimated coefficient obtained by ordinary least squares regression?

Tags: r, regression, expected-value, simulation, computational-statistics

Let $(X_1,Y_1),(X_2,Y_2),\dots,(X_5,Y_5)$ be i.i.d samples and consider the regression model
$$
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \varepsilon_i, \quad \quad \text{for} \ i \in \{1,2,\dots,5\},
$$
where $\varepsilon_i|X \sim \mathcal(0,\sigma^2)$, and $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$. When we solve it with least squares we find the estimated regression coefficients $\hat \beta_0$ and $\hat \beta_1$.

Now, consider the expectation $E[f(\hat \beta_1 X_5)]$ where $f(x) = e^{-1/2x^2}$. Note that the expression for $\hat \beta_1$ is known explicitly, it is
$$
\hat \beta_1 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^5 (X_i - \overline X)(Y_i - \overline Y)}{\sum_{i=1}^5 (X_i - \overline X)^2}.
$$
where $\overline X$ and $\overline Y$ are the sample means.

I am wondering is it possible to computationally estimate the expectation $E[f(\hat \beta_1 X_5)]$ and if so can it be done efficiently? It seems like a very complicated function of multiple random variables so I have no idea if it is even feasible to model and compute an estimate of this quantity.

Comment: do you know the mean and variance of the $X_i$ random variable?

Comment: @LucasRoberts It is fine to take $\mu_X = 5$ and $\sigma_X^2 = 2$. For the error I have $\sigma^2 = 1$.

Comment: OK, $X_5$ isn't a random variable. You already assume for the OLS regression that there is no error associated to it. You can assume a normal distribution for $\hat \beta_1$ and thus also $\hat \beta_1 X_5$ (the standard error of of $\hat \beta_1$ is derived from the model fit as usual). Then you just need to apply the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Comment: If you want to consider $X_5$ a random variable, you need to apply orthogonal regression instead of OLS regression. In that case, I think you need a MC simulation to solve this.

Comment: @Roland $X_5$ is a random variable, I specified all the $X_i$ are normally distributed. This is regression with stochastic regressors, not fixed regressors.

Comment: I want to be able to compute an estimate of $E[f(\hat \beta_1X_5)]$ in R but I don't know how to formulate it so that I can implement it computationally.

Comment: Is this really the function you need to estimate?  I ask because (1) it has no apparent statistical interpretation and (2) a general answer may be intractable, but accurate answers in many cases (depending on the underlying parameters) are possible and (3) the sampling distribution of this function tends to be *extremely* skewed, indicating that an expected value might not be worth much.